# Apt error message on my Debian 10 Buster Linux on Chrome OS

Tags: debian, apt

I'm having an error message in my Linux terminal after trying to install adb debugging sideloader through my Chrome OS. I don't think it has anything to do with that, the error message I'm seeing when I run `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb` is:

```
E: Type 'new' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What is this error message and how do I fix it?

Comment: It continues to show when when I try to install other things in my Linux terminal too

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`; add to your question.

Comment: Welcome, please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line to override the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and solving the following error (error come from the line 4) see [debian wiki: Sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) :

```
E: Type 'new' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Open the terminal and paste the following lines:

```
cat <<-EOF |  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
EOF

sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install android-tools-adb
```

Comment: Thanks M8  Do you know if this works with XAPKS too?

Answer (score 2):

Post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or if you first want to check you can see if line 4 in that file looks different then the rest.  It appears that your sources.list got corrupted somehow probably when you where trying to install the sideloader.

Jason C.

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied

Comment: Am I typing the way to view this correctly, or is it something else? Im new to Linux so step by step breakdowns would be nice

Comment: Ok it’s extremely early posting this from my phone I will type up a complete guide when I get back from work.

Comment: Ive already been answered but an explanation would still be nice thanks though